# How to copy file from downloads to filesystem/bin?

Tags: clipboard, privileges, permissions

I am pretty new to Ubuntu 12.04. I have a problem using my datacard on it, so I got a program called Sakis 3G. This program is a file after downloading; it opens in gedit. I need to copy this file to the `bin` folder in File System. But, it shows a permission error. Can anybody help me out? How to copy this using Terminal with the full command? The file is in Downloads folder and I need to copy it to `bin` folder in File System without errors.

Comment: While sometimes it is correct to manually copy files into `/bin`, usually you should not do this. Can you provide more information about what you're trying to do? Are there instructions online that you're attempting to follow? I recommend **editing your question** to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
sudo cp Downloads/"sakis 3G" /bin/
```

PS: Are you sure the name has a space in it?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you just want to be able to execute your executable for the shell, without giving the full path to the executable.

The `PATH` environment variable holds the directories that are searched when executing an arbitrary command in a shell. Just type `echo $PATH` in a shell and you will see the searched directories, separated by a `:`.

The thing now is that it is generally a bad idea to put your own links or executables into the `/bin` folder, you would rather put them into the `/usr/local/bin` folder (which is usually empty unless you put something in there), as this folder is used for exactly that purpose. See the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for more information about placing files under linux.

@mikewhatever already answered the permission problem.

> This program is a file after downloading; it opens in gedit.

What's the file type you want to open? Give some more details please. Do you see text that makes sense? Or just garbage in `gedit`? You probably have to set the executable bit for the file `chmod +x <file-name>` to make it work properly.

That being said, you have to be careful when manually creating files in the file-system (not speaking about your home folder), as nearly all files are managed by a package management system. If possible, i would search for a solution to install your software as a package.